# My jQuery form validation isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to make this piece of code work. But there is something wrong with it. I don't know what. Anyone care to help here.
Thanks
The problem is that when the form is submitted and it doesn't show any validation messages.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$f_name=$_POST['f_name'];
$cell=$_POST['cell_no'];
$_SESSION['name']=$name;
$_SESSION['f_name']=$f_name;
$_SESSION['cell']=$cell;



}

?>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myForm").validate({

            rules: {
                name: "required",
                f_name: "required",
                cell_no: {
                    required: true,
                    minlenght: 11
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please state your name.",
                f_name: "Father name is required.",
                cell_no: {
                    required: "Please provide a contact number.",
                    minlength: "Minimum length is 11 digits"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }

        });

    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>

<?php  
echo @$_GET['sheikh'];    
?>
</center>


<form method="POST" action="" id="myForm" novalidate="novalidate">
<center><h1>First Form</h1></center>
<h2>Basic Information</h2>
Name:<input type="text" name="name">
Father name:<input type="text" name="f_name">
Cell_no:<input type="text" name="cell_no">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="next">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where have you included the jquery validate.js file ??

Comment: You need to call [jquery.validate.js](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try checking the console log when you have this kind of issues.
You will come to know what is the problem.

when the page loads it shows,

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function"

this means the required library not exists with you code. 
Download it and insert in your page like

> script src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js"

you did or give direct link if you doing this for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Problems in your script:

1. You have included `jQuery` twice on the page
2. You haven't included `jQuery.validate.js`

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @MashhoodAli jQuery should be included first and then jquery.validate.js